# input the data from url Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get the value from link and then add them to DB.

I am working with another developer who created an api as a bridge because he does not know Laravel. Here is the api http://laravel.io/bin/614Xv I am currently passing string valued data like so http://laravel.io/bin/wYry0 and passing the parameters $user, $name, $password through the route.

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/profile/activated/{user?}/{pass?}/{email?}', array(
        'as' => 'invited-user-account-created-get',
        'uses' => 'ProfileController@getCreateInvitedUser'
));
```

Here is my function:

```
public function getCreateInvitedUser($user=null, $password=null, $email=null) {
    $user = Input::get('username', 'abcd');
    $pass = Input::get('password', '1234');
    $email = Input::get('email', 'asas@gam.com');

    //insert $user array in database users table
    $user = User::create(array(
        'username'      =>  $user,
        'password'      =>  $pass,
        'email'     =>  $email
        ));

}
```

The other developer is wanting me to set the input to the variables I get from the url link/profile/activated/user/pass/email

Maybe I am tired but I am not understanding what he wants me to do and how to grab the variables from the url. The whole reason in doing this is to instantly store the invited guest info in the database when they click the activation link so they do not have to sign up for an account later.

Comment: if that route is working, the problem is your overwriting the values passed to it in that method. those first 3 lines of that method totally overwrite the variables that are passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Your route has a problem

Use this instead

```
Route::get('/profile/activated/{user}/{pass}/{email}', array(
    'as' => 'invited-user-account-created-get',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@getCreateInvitedUser'
));
```

But his idea is totally messed up! Passing password values through a URL, Who does that even? 
You sound enlightened, please advise him to try a different approach in whatever thing he's trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. My route is fine because the "?" makes it optional to pass parameters. http://laravel.com/docs/routing

Comment: However, you are right, I do not see what the other developer is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Billy Oh alright! Just advise him on the [PHP Best Practices](http://thisinterestsme.com/php-best-practises/)

Comment: yes, I ended up letting him go because he is just creating a mess.